# dict's __repr__() in python2 and python3

Tags: python, testing, python-2.7, python-3.x, repr

I'm porting a python library from python 2 only to python 2 and 3 in one codebase (2.6, 2.7 and 3.3+). The main problem left is that a lot of tests use something like this:

```
def test(self):
 example = {u'foo': u'bar'}
 self.assertEqual(str(example), "{u'foo': u'bar'}")
```

which works in python 2, but raises an exception in python3:

```
 AssertionError: "{'foo': 'bar'}" != "{u'foo': u'bar'}"
```

Is there a standard way of dealing with these problems apart from 'test different'? overloading`__repr__`?

Comment: Why do you have these tests? What are they attempting to verify? This smells very strongly of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: to clarify: in the actual code, *example* is a subclass of dict and is the return value of another function. this subclass has it's own `__repr__`, wrapping dict's `__repr__`, but the 'u's are still in there

Comment: That doesn't clarify _anything_. What are you actually trying to test here? Is the problem that the subclass's `__eq__` doesn't work right with a base `dict` object, so you're trying to work around it by comparing their `repr`? Or…?

Comment: @ChristianGeier: you are comparing against a fixed string; generate the fixed string with or without `u` prefixes if you *have* to test the custom `__repr__`.

Comment: @ChristianGeier: Test the actual output, don't try and make the function output match the test at all cost.

Comment: @abarnert `__eq__` does work, I have no idea why the original author tested via `__repr__`. I guess I'll just use that and be done with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get rid of those tests; they are next to useless:

- This tests if the Python implementation of `dict.__repr__` is working. Python itself already tests for this; focus on the project codebase instead. If Python fails to render a dictionary representation correctly it's not your project's job to fix that.
- Python dictionaries have no fixed ordering; testing if their representation matches a given string is not going to be stable.

  Moreover, Python 3.3 introduces hash randomization, meaning that the order of a given dictionary will change from invocation to invocation. See [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED).

If you are testing the result of a project API calll, test for dictionary equality using [`self.assertEqual()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) instead; it'll use [`assertDictEqual()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertDictEqual) to give you meaningful error messages if the two dictionaries do not match.

Since Python 3.3 interprets `u'foo'` as a literal for type `str`, comparing output against `{u'foo': u'bar}` will work across Python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.3 and newer.

Comment: Also, in python3 strings became unicode by default. That means standard strings don't have thet `u` prefix anymore.

Comment: Checking `self.assertEqual(example, ast.literal_eval({u'foo': u'bar'}))` is less impossible, and serves a _similar_ purpose… but I still can't imagine what that purpose might be, so it's hard to say whether it's similar _enough_.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, to be fair, ordering is irrelevant in *this* example:  `len(example) == 1`.

Comment: `assertDictEqual` doesn't exist in 2.6. And in 2.7 and 3.3, while it does exist, "This method will be used by default to compare dictionaries in calls to `assertEqual()`", so it doesn't add much.

Comment: @TimPeters: sure; but the OP is not testing length; he is testing if the Python `dict.__repr__()` is still working..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And he's testing that `unicode` strings are represented exactly the same way as in CPython 2.7 (with the `u` prefix, and the same rules for when to use single quotes vs. double and when to escape, and so on) too, which is even _less_ useful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes, I know that.  This is trivial, not deep ;-)  The `repr()` of a 1-element dict is 100% reproducible, regardless of hash used, order of insertions/deletions, etc.  The only problem with *this specific example* is that Python 3 dropped the `u` prefix.

Comment: @TimPeters: Ah, I see what you are getting at; yes, a one-element dictionary has a 100% predictable order.

Comment: @TimPeters: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't it be perfectly legal for a different Python 3.x implementation to use double quotes instead of single quotes in this example? (Or, for that matter, to put in the useless `u` prefixes, although I can't imagine anyone would do that even if it were legal…)

Comment: @abarnert, yes, quite legal - very little about the `repr()` of *anything* is defined.  Heck, I think `repr({1: 2})` producing `"***!it's a dict!***"` would be "legal" ;-)  As a practical matter, though, gratuitous changes are unlikely.

Comment: @TimPeters: OK, I was assuming that an implementation would try to follow the "Return something `eval`-able if possible and a good idea, something clearly non-`eval`-able otherwise" rule that all of the existing ones do… but I guess you're right, nothing requires even that much.

Comment: @abarmert, of course in *practice* Python developers strive to make `repr()` "round-trippable" when practical.  But they also strive to avoid gratuitous differences across releases and implementations.  There's really no chance that, e.g., an implementation would choose to use single instead of double quotes (or vice versa) "for no reason at all".

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that this isn't your real code, and your real code is doing something slightly less silly: trying to verify that a dictionary matches some expected result.

The way to do this is to compare the dictionaries directly, instead of comparing their string representations:

```
self.assertEqual(example, {u'foo': u'bar'})
```

This will work in both 2.x and 3.x (since you're requiring 3.3+, which means the `u` prefixes are legal, if unnecessary).